# CSHTML Overlapping Footer with Side Navigation

Tags: c#, html, css, model-view-controller, razor

The sidebar is overlapping with Footer, as shown in the below image
[image]

I want the footer to be after the fixed to bottom.
My Layout is as below
Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <!-- Begin page -->
    <div id="layout-wrapper ">
        <div class="desktop-menu">

        <!-- Header -->
        @Html.Partial("_Header")
        <!-- End Header -->
        <!-- Left Sidebar -->
        @Html.Partial("_LeftSidebar")
        <!-- End Left Sidebar -->
        </div>
        <!-- ============================================================== -->
        <!-- Start right Content here -->
        <!-- ============================================================== -->
        <div class="main-content">
                <!-- Start content -->
                @RenderBody()
                <!-- End content -->
            <!-- End Page-content -->            
        </div>
        <!-- end main content-->
       
    <!-- Footer -->
    @Html.Partial("_Footer")
    <!-- End Footer -->
</body>
</html>
```

_leftSidebar.cshtml

```
 <div class="vertical-menu position-fixed">
        <!-- LOGO -->
        <div data-simplebar class="sidebar-menu-scroll">
            <!--- Sidemenu -->
            <div id="sidebar-menu">
                <!-- Left Menu Start -->
                    <ul class="metismenu list-unstyled" id="side-menu">
                        <button type="button" id="side-short"
                            class="btn btn-sm px-3 font-size-16 header-item vertical-menu-btn">
                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-bars"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button"
                            class="btn btn-sm px-3 font-size-16 header-item vertical-menu-btn vertical-menu-btn-one">
                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-bars"></i>
                    </button>
                    <li class="menu-title">Menu</li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html" class="active">
                            <div class="home-menu">
                                <span class="icon-home icon"></span>
                                <span class="menu-title-one">Home</span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="ins-listing">
                        <a href="javascript: void(0);" class="has-arrow-one ">
                            <div class="home-menu home-menu-one has-arrow">
                                <span class="icon-Instance icon"></span>
                                <span class="menu-title-one">test</span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu" aria-expanded="true">
                            <li>
                                <a href="test.html">test</a>

                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="test.html">test</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>  </ul>
                }
                       </div>
    </div>
```

_footer.cshtml

```
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-6">
                <ul class="footer-ul">
                    <div class="footer-titel">Quick Links</div>
                    <div class="footer-border"></div>
                    <li>test</li>
                    <li>test</li>
                    <li>test</li>
                </ul>
            </div>                    
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row copye">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            &copy; test
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="text-sm-end d-none d-sm-block">
                <b>Version</b> 1.0
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.vertical-menu {
     width: 250px;
     background: var(--bs-sidebar-bg);
     bottom: 0;
     margin-top: 0;
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(15, 34, 58, .12);
     box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(15, 34, 58, .12)
}

.footer {
     bottom: 0;
     padding:50px calc(1.25rem / 2);
     right: 0;
     color: var(--bs-footer-color);
     z-index: 1001;
     position: relative;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(15, 34, 58, .12);
     box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(15, 34, 58, .12)
}
```

I would like to have the footer not overlap with the side navigation contents,  when I scroll down the footer is overlapping with side navigation and menu gets hidden

Answer (score 0):

Set a higher z-index for .footer to ensure it's above the sidebar.

```
.vertical-menu {
    (your current styles)
    z-index: 999;
}

.footer {
   (your current styles)
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: It's above sidebar only, but it's overlapping with it's content, side bar content are getting hidden

Answer (score 0):

Try `*` to apply elements.

```
.vertical-menu, .vertical-menu * {
    (your current styles)
    z-index: 100;
}

.footer, .footer * {
   (your current styles)
    z-index: 200;
}
```